# How to safely access object property with space (JSONP property like "First Name" : "...")

Tags: typescript, jsdoc

How to annotate this objects so I will get compiler error or warning if I try to access property that does not exists?

```
{
  "Id": 1
  "First Name": "Lorem",
  "Last Name": "Ipsum",
}
```

I've annotated this object using this definition:

```
interface Person{
  Id: number;
  "First Name": string;
  "Last Name": string;
}
```

however, I'm still not able to safely access the "First Name" property, since the only way to access it is:

```
var person : Person = ...;
var firstName = person["First Name"];
```

not only that this returns any, but it allows to access undefined properties, like `person['bla bla']` without compiler error.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have you us indexes like `"First Name"`?
Because that's what's causes the problems, consider this code:

```
interface Person {
    Id: number;
    FirstName: string;
    LastName: string;
}

var person : Person = { Id: 3, FirstName: "fname", LastName: "lname" };
var firstName = person.FirstName;
var illegal = person.nothing; // error
var legal = person["nothing"]; // ok
```

([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Person%20%7B%0A%09Id%3A%20number%3B%0A%09FirstName%3A%20string%3B%0A%09LastName%3A%20string%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20person%20%3A%20Person%20%3D%20%7B%20Id%3A%203%2C%20FirstName%3A%20%22fname%22%2C%20LastName%3A%20%22lname%22%20%7D%3B%0Avar%20firstName%20%3D%20person.FirstName%3B%0Avar%20illegal%20%3D%20person.nothing%3B%0Avar%20legal%20%3D%20person%5B%22nothing%22%5D%3B))

When I try `person.nothing` then it complains that the interface `Person` doesn't have this property, but when I try `person["nothing"]` it does not complain.

Comment: Yes, I do have to used that format, since I don't own the data. When I annotate the object like me, with quotes, typescript validates assignments like `var person: Person = { ... }`

Comment: Yes, this kind of assignment checks the properties, like when you use the dot notation (`person.FirstName`). I'm not aware of how to make the compiler validate the property name when you use it as an index (`person["First Name"]`), but maybe someone else here know how.